# Why can't approvers see workbox initial state items but admins can?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

We have a small pool of approvers that are also active content editors. That means that they need to monitor the workbox and make and approve their own edits.

We used to give everyone admin access, but that lets you completely skip workflow very easily. We have several programatic steps within workflow that we want to always execute. Plus it is generally bad practice to have most users be administrators.

We thought everything was working fine with our approvers in standard roles, but one of the users discovered that they could see several additional items in the initial workflow state when logged in as a full admin that they could not see as themselves.

A typical scenario would be that one of their peers locked an item, but never submitted.

I looked at permissions on their role and they seem to have all of the appropriate rights.

[Screenshot of Access Viewer for the user in question on an item that is locked by another user, but does not show up in the first user's workbox.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nJD7.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Workflow and Security go hand in hand and can be a bit tricky. It is rather hard to answer your question without fully seeing your users, roles and applied security for all items (content & workflow).

From the [workflow reference document](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/workflow_reference-usletter_sc60-64.pdf) section 3.4.1:

> The effective access rights on an item can influence the behavior of the Workbox application. A user must 
>   have write access to an item in order to see the item in the Workbox. Note that a user may not have write 
>   access to an item if the item is currently checked out (locked) by another user.

Furthermore:

> Users who have read access to a workflow state can see that state in their workbox as long as the state includes workflow commands for which they have command execute access rights.

If running through this document does not provide any assistance, you may need to clarify your question with details around role hierarchies and permissions on items. Perhaps a [lightweight Sitecore security report](http://seankearney.com/post/Sitecore-Security-Report-and-Reset.aspx) would be useful for reporting back your settings.

Comment: The part about write access seems logical. Now what do I do if they don't care and they want to see all of those in the Workbox?